# What is the process of dynamic sitemap creation?

Tags: seo, sitemap

I am working on a website which have 12Lack pages, so, I want build dynamic sitemap hence I want to know the process of dynamic sitemap creation. tell me if have another way to create sitemap for such of pages.

Thanks
Pawan

Comment: You can create it in which ever way easy for you, in your language of linking(C/C++/PHP etc). Please read http://www.sitemaps.org to learn the format of Sitemap

Answer (score 1):

Google maintains a large list of software programs that can create sitemap files here: https://code.google.com/p/sitemap-generators/wiki/SitemapGenerators

These programs may enumerate the URLs on your site in one of three ways:

- Crawling your site
- Analyzing your log files
- Reading your database

### Server Side Programs

Written in cross platform scripting languages, these programs would run on your server and appear to generally get your data by crawling the site.

### CMS and other plugins

These would integrate into the software that runs your website and would get the list of urls by examining the database.

### Downloadable Tools

Software that you can install and run on your home computer to crawl your website and create a sitemap file

### Online Generators/Services

Websites that you could ask to crawl your site for you, then download a created sitemap from them.